# Controlling power series by a function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, sequence-of-function

I was working on a problem where the following power series was considered
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+2^n}
$$
I found the interval of convergence: $-2<x<2$.
Then they as to prove that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+2^n} \leqslant \dfrac{x}{2-x},        \forall 0\leqslant x <2.
$$
Does anyone can help on how to prove such inequality, or let me know how I can start with it.

Comment: can you find a power series for the right hand side $x/(2-x)$?

Comment: Do you want an evaluation of the sum as well?

Comment: No all what I need is to prove this inequality. But I think one can maximize the series by another one geometric with ratio x/2, this could work I think

Comment: The inequality is wrong as the first term of the LHS is  always equal to $1$ while the RHS is equal to zero for $x=0$. It would be correct if the RHS would be $\frac{2}{2-x}$.

Comment: No it is not wrong, and if we take n=0 on the LHS this doesn't mean that the RHS is zero

Comment: @Student The LHS is $\ge 1$ whatever the value of $x$. But the RHS is equal to zero for $x=0$. Hence the inequality is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\le x \lt2$ $$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+2^n} \le
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{2^n} =\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}} =\frac{2}{2-x}$$ using the sum of the terms of  geometric series.

*But the inequality of the question is not correct.*

Comment: Many thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks for that… however, the inequality of the question is wrong. See my comment.

Comment: Yep, correct @mathcounterexamples.net, $x=0$ providing a case in point.

Answer (score 0):

What you think about that??
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+2^n} \leqslant \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{2^n} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^n = \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}
$$

Comment: I think there is nothing here that is not already in the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes sorry, when I write it the correct answer was not appeared on my phone thats why I write it

Answer (score 0):

The inequality seems to be wrong.

But we can do the following.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+2^n}\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[\dfrac{x}{2}\right]^n = \dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{x}{2}}=\dfrac{2}{2-x}.$$

At the same time we can write

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+2^n}\geq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{2^n+2^n} = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{x}{2}\right]^n=\dfrac{1}{2-x}.$$

Hence, we can conclude

$$\dfrac{1}{2-x} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n+2^n}\leq \dfrac{2}{2-x}$$

Comment: So it is not possible to obtain x in the RHS of the inequality, so this is the mistake with the question.

Comment: You could use 2/(2-x) + x as a more loose bound. But why do you want to have $x$ in there the current expression is easier.

Comment: The question was like that and I was stuck with it, that's why I ask the question here.